# How can I make `file` output line break type and encoding for all file types?

Tags: character-encoding, text, newlines

I often find myself in the need to check the encoding and the line break type of a file.

The `file` utility seems to be a perfect fit. Unfortunately it doesn't output the desired information for all file types. For example it doesn't do so on `.php` files.

**For example:**

```
file extra.module.php
```

> extra.module.php: PHP script text

But if I rename the file to `.txt` and remove the PHP starting tag, it outputs both.

```
file extra.module.txt
```

> extra.module.txt: UTF-8 Unicode C++ program text, with CRLF line
>   terminators

I already looked at the manpage and I can use the `-i` switch to force outputting the character encoding, but there seems to be no switch for the line break type.

Is there a simple solution for this without renaming/changing the file first?

Comment: See comments under _RedGrittyBrick_'s [answer here](http://superuser.com/a/460175)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @don_crissti's comment, it turns out that passing an empty magicfile to `file` will make it fall back to detect the default ASCII.

So `file -m /dev/null extra.module.php` will do the trick in this case and will output the desired

> extra.module.php: UTF-8 Unicode C++ program text, with CRLF line terminators